How do the entangled photons from an SPDC source behave?
As I understand SPDC sources emit entangled photons, but always in the same polarisation. If this source always outputs this certain polarisation are the photons then still in superposition of each other or are they just orthogonal?
Say, for example, it is an type-2 SPDC source and I measure both signal and idler photons at 45 degrees of their standard polarisation. Would I indeed see that the signal is randomly entering either 0 or 1, but that the idler is always giving the other signal. Or would they both be random in this case?

Any polarized photon measured at 45 degrees to its axis has a 50/50 chance of being passed/reflected.

From the answer to this question
„Polarized particles are clearly fixed in their direction. Entangled particles, on the other hand, have a randomness in their common alignment with each other. "Up" and "down" therefore do not adequately describe entanglement. It is precisely the common and random orientation of the photons in space that falsifies the result of the forced orientation of the measuring apparatus and only with repeated measurements and statistical methods is the entanglement proven.“

Consider to spell out acronyms.

If the state of the system is an entangled state, like a singlet
$$
|\Psi^-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|\uparrow \downarrow\rangle - |\downarrow \uparrow\rangle)
$$
Then if the first particle measures $\uparrow$, the second particle will measure $\downarrow$ with certainty, i.e.
$$
P(s_2=\downarrow|s_1=\uparrow) = 1.
$$
We could say that we have Perfect anti-correlation in this case, since
$$
P(s_1\neq s_2) = \langle \Psi^-| P_{s_1\neq s_2} |\Psi^-\rangle = 1
$$
Where
$$
P_{s_1\neq s_2} = |\uparrow\downarrow\rangle\!\langle \uparrow\downarrow| + |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\!\langle \downarrow\uparrow|.
$$
Now, if the second photon is measured, without information about the first photon, it will be described by a maximally mixed state
$$
\rho_2 = \frac 12 |\uparrow\rangle\!\langle \uparrow | + \frac 12 |\downarrow\rangle\!\langle \downarrow|.
$$
Whose results are completely random.

The singlet is a special case where we have maximally entangled states. For partial entangled states, one could have not perfect correlated results. The correlation of observables are related with the notion of entanglement, as you can see in my answer here

Not sure I understand the question, but it seems to be about the local unitaries. What this means is: entanglement is invariant under the application of unitary transformations to a single sub-system. For example, if the initial state is
$$ |\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|H\rangle_A|V\rangle_B 
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|V\rangle_A|H\rangle_B , $$
then a local unitary transformation of the $A$ system can for example be
$$ |H\rangle_A \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|D\rangle_A 
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|A\rangle_A 
~~~ \text{and} ~~~ |V\rangle_A \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|D\rangle_A 
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|A\rangle_A . $$
When we apply this transformation, the entangled state becomes
$$ \begin{aligned}
|\psi\rangle & = \frac{1}{2}\left(|D\rangle_A 
+|A\rangle_A\right)|V\rangle_B 
+\frac{1}{2}\left(|D\rangle_A 
-|A\rangle_A\right)|H\rangle_B \\
 & = \frac{1}{2}|D\rangle_A\left(|H\rangle_B 
+|V\rangle_B\right) 
-\frac{1}{2}|A\rangle_A\left(|H\rangle_B 
-|V\rangle_B\right) \\
 & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|D\rangle_A|D\rangle_B  
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|A\rangle_A|A\rangle_B .
\end{aligned} $$
So the result is that the state is still entangled (the amount of entanglement is the same), even though the basis vectors are different.
Therefore, if we change the polarization form vertical-horizontal to diagonal-antidiagonal, we get the same correlations, provided both measurements in $A$ and $B$ are done in the same basis. If their bases are not the same the results are random. (This is the basic principle behind for quantum key distribution.)
Another point that may be relevant in the context of SPDC is that the entanglement is not only in the polarization degrees of freedom but also in the other degrees of freedom. For type I phase matching, there is no entanglement in polarization.
